# Ruby on Rails belongs_to vs. has_one associations - clarification requested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

In the following instance, what would the difference be between using belongs_to :mother and has_one :mother for the Chlid class? I've been reading the Rails documentation on this and I can't see how either one would make a difference apart from the semantics involved with reading it.

From what I can tell, the various associations add extra methods to each class, but I haven't been able to find the documentation to list per association what the methods are and what they do.

```
class BiologicalMother < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :biological_mother
end
```

Comment: Here's the official documentation for "Choosing Between belongs_to and has_one" : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one and it says: `"The distinction is in where you place the foreign key (it goes on the table for the class declaring the belongs_to association)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the `has_many` `belongs_to` is the right approach not just semantically but as how rails works. The foreign key is always stored in the `belongs_to` part of the association.
A valid `has_one` scenario could be like having a `Purchase` model which `has_one` `BillingAddress`.

example:

```
class Purchase
   has_one :billing_address
end

class BillingAddress
   belongs_to :purchase #this holds the foreign key - purchase_id
end
```

Regarding your case, you cant use `has_many` in one side and `has_one` at the other side of the association because the `belongs_to` part holds the foreign key always.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: That was the explanation I needed to help me understand, especially that I couldn't use has_one and has_many on opposing models [even though that did seem to be discouraged, I didn't know why]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At this point, it's almost purely semantics. With mongoid, I know that the foreign key is stored on the model with the `belongs_to`, so there might be something like that with ActiveRecord too.